# Bootstrap carousel caption does not show up in fullscreen 1920 x 1080?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to figure out why carousel-caption will not display in a blown up 1920x1080 window.  If the window isn't blown up then the caption shows fine.  The code in question:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/banner-1.jpg" alt="Competitive Prices on Web Design, SEO, and Digital Marketing" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Quality Web Design</h3>
        <p>Simple and Elegant Web Design, Located in Rochester Hills, Michigan</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/banner-3.jpg" alt="Get Your Business Online Today" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Get Your Business Online Today!</h3>
        <p> ... </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/banner-2.jpg" alt="Drive Traffic to Your Site" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>SEO</h3>
        <p>Proper search engine optimization may make or break your website's visibility!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can see it in action here: http://foxpile.net/wordpress/

When I replace the images with one outside of the theme (I've used http://placehold.it/1920x500 .. everything seems to work correctly)

I am running on the latest version of Wordpress and Bootstrap 3.2.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `top: 46%;` in the `.carousel-caption` while resolution greater than `1280px`. This will fix the issue try inspecting with code inspector like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) etc.

Find following media query in bootstrap or if you are over-riding Bootstrap CSS than add this in over-riding css file;

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  .carousel-caption
  {
    top: 46%;
  }
}
```

on larger resolution caption moves down wards have more offset on top and does not show due to container `overflow hidden`. What i did on resolution greater than `1200px` i have i reduced caption top offset. This make it show on even `1920x1080p`.

good luck!

Comment: Ahh this makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The images coming with your theme have a 1920x650 size, while the carousel has an explicit `max-height` specified

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

Using your placeholder images lead to having an image that is smaller, and thus will display until someone with a wider screen arrives.

The solution is either to:

- allow the banner to grow over 500px (by removing this max-height)
- use images with a height smaller or equal to 500px, but you need in that case to define their behavior on a bigger screen
- change the position of the caption to be relative to the carousel, and not to the item

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is relatively an old post, this could be helpful for some people. You may also just add fixed height value to `.item` divs:

**[PenCode 1](https://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/LzeVPP)**

```css
.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 400px;  /* add this */
}
```

This approach has another benefit if you add the images as background images for `.item` divs rather than images, and add `background-size:cover;` to the `.item` CSS, you'll get a responsive image without having to deal with images height for small screens.

**[CodePen 2](https://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/dVJoQN?editors=1100)**

<sub>* Resize both pens and see the difference height</sub>